# How to implement an app-specific configuration?

Tags: c#, configuration

my applications use a config file (XML) to set seldomly changed, user-specific ViewModel Properties.
Like materials, country data, etc.

So at the start op the app, this XML is read in and parameters are set.
I programmed all this myself (XmlSerializer).

Are there any standard (PD?) facilities (eg. C#/VS extensions) I could incorporate, instead of carving my own stuff?

My app users must have access to the XML file themselves, to adapt the app to their local conditions.

To paint the desired situation:

For logging i use Log4Net

For generating graphs I use OxyPlot

Comment: app.config is what you´re looking for.

Comment: But app.config is not always accessible for a user: on centrally managed PC...
I read about ConfigurationManager. Can that handle any XML ? (Complex elements)